# Can I use \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory outside of setup install scripts?

Tags: magento2, eav, category-attribute

Can I instantiate `Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup` outside of setup install scripts in Magento 2?

I specifically want to use the function `Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup::addAttributeToGroup` to programmatically add category attributes to a group.

Comment: Yes you can use this function outside of install scripts.

Comment: How do I instantiate the class in order to use it?